# Laravel Vue Spa - Custom js script refusing to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I recently installed a fresh [Laravel Vue Spa Project](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa) and I wanted to use a custom theme, [CoolAdmin Template](https://github.com/puikinsh/CoolAdmin) instead of the one that came with the project.

But one of the js script [main.js](https://github.com/puikinsh/CoolAdmin/blob/master/js/main.js) is refusing to work, load or fire up. Therefore the hamburger menu, dropdown menus and so many other, are not working. I have tried compiling the file using **Webpack.mix.js** and even importing the script to **app.js** and compiling it but it still didn't work.

I dont know if the problem is coming from the script itself, but it works very well in the template without the laravel vue project. This is the script

```js
(function ($) {
  // USE STRICT
  "use strict";

  // Dropdown 
  try {
    var menu = $('.js-item-menu');
    var sub_menu_is_showed = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      $(menu[i]).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.js-right-sidebar').removeClass("show-sidebar");        
        if (jQuery.inArray(this, menu) == sub_menu_is_showed) {
          $(this).toggleClass('show-dropdown');
          sub_menu_is_showed = -1;
        }
        else {
          for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            $(menu[i]).removeClass("show-dropdown");
          }
          $(this).toggleClass('show-dropdown');
          sub_menu_is_showed = jQuery.inArray(this, menu);
        }
      });
    }
    $(".js-item-menu, .js-dropdown").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body,html").on("click", function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        menu[i].classList.remove("show-dropdown");
      }
      sub_menu_is_showed = -1;
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  var wW = $(window).width();
    // Right Sidebar
    var right_sidebar = $('.js-right-sidebar');
    var sidebar_btn = $('.js-sidebar-btn');

    sidebar_btn.on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        menu[i].classList.remove("show-dropdown");
      }
      sub_menu_is_showed = -1;
      right_sidebar.toggleClass("show-sidebar");
    });

    $(".js-right-sidebar, .js-sidebar-btn").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body,html").on("click", function () {
      right_sidebar.removeClass("show-sidebar");

    });
 

  // Sublist Sidebar
  try {
    var arrow = $('.js-arrow');
    arrow.each(function () {
      var that = $(this);
      that.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        that.find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        that.toggleClass("open");
        that.parent().find('.js-sub-list').slideToggle("250");
      });
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }


  try {
    // Hamburger Menu
    $('.hamburger').on('click', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
      $('.navbar-mobile').slideToggle('500');
    });
    $('.navbar-mobile__list li.has-dropdown > a').on('click', function () {
      var dropdown = $(this).siblings('ul.navbar-mobile__dropdown');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $(dropdown).slideToggle('500');
      return false;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})(jQuery);
(function ($) {
  // USE STRICT
  "use strict";

  // Load more
  try {
    var list_load = $('.js-list-load');
    if (list_load[0]) {
      list_load.each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        that.find('.js-load-item').hide();
        var load_btn = that.find('.js-load-btn');
        load_btn.on('click', function (e) {
          $(this).text("Loading...").delay(1500).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).hide();
            that.find(".js-load-item").fadeToggle("slow", 'swing');
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      })

    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please help, is there any other way I can get this script to work or fire up

**DEBUGGING**
So after some debugging, it turns out that the code stops loading after the **for loop** and the `”use strict” doesn’t work` . **Please help**

Answer (score 0):

You should know that Laravel is using [Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix) to compile Js code (based on Webpack).
Therefore I recommend you to load the `main.js` file using mix and import the Jquery directly in your `bootstrap.js` without using CDN.
ex:

```
mix.scripts(['resources/js/main.js'], 'public/js')
```

Also, you have to load Jquery before any other scripts.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But I just tried that, and it also didn't work.. Please is there any other way?